# How to filter WooCommerce products by custom attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I'm trying to filter WooCommerce product archive by custom attributes.

For example, there are 5 products with attribute "color" containing "red", and another 3 with attribute "color" containing "blue".

How can I apply a filter to the products loop, so only the products containing "red" will be shown?

Thanks

Comment: For example you can look code on this free plugin: http://www.woocommerce-filter.com/ - its using native woocommerce API

Comment: @realmag777 suggesting a plugin inside a coding platform seems to be funny to me

Comment: You can find a working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74200775/how-can-i-filter-woocommerce-shop-products-product-loop-by-their-custom-produc

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On one of my sites I had to make a custom search by a lot of data some of it from custom fields here is how my $args look like for one of the options:

```php
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    'tax_query' => array(
        $query_tax
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'ad_listing',
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order,
    'paged' => $paged
);
```

where "$meta_query" is:

```php
$key = "your_custom_key"; //custom_color for example
$value = "blue";//or red or any color
$query_color = array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value);
$meta_query[] = $query_color;
```

and after that:

```php
query_posts($args);
```

so you would probably get more info here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
and you can search for "meta_query" in the page to get to the info

Comment: I were looking for a way to do it with native Woo functions, but it seems like there're no functions for that. However, I end up with something similar to that, by modifying the $query_string. Thanks

Comment: Could you please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526268/sql-query-to-download-order-report-in-woocommerce .

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [WooCommerce Layered Nav widget](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-widgets/#section-3), which allows you to use different sets of attributes as filters for products. Here's the "official" description:

> Shows a custom attribute in a widget which lets you narrow down the list of products when viewing product categories.

If you look into plugins/woocommerce/widgets/widget-layered_nav.php, you can see the way it operates with the attributes in order to set filters. The URL then looks like this:

http://yoursite.com/shop/?filtering=1&filter_min-kvadratura=181&filter_max-kvadratura=108&filter_obem-ohlajdane=111

... and the digits are actually the id-s of the different attribute values, that you want to set.