# Woocommerce: Show products filtered by attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to filter products by attribute in Woocommerce using a checkbox or alternatively a link. If I mark the checkbox or click the link I want get all products that have this attribute.

How can I do this? Which files should I edit?

Edit: Now i need do a query to get all products that have a custom attribute 'demo' in my case.

I'm doing this:

```
$args = array ( 'meta_query' => array( 
array( 'key' => 'meta_value', 
       'value' => 'demo', 
       'compare' => 'LIKE', ), 
       ), 
);
```

Whats wrong??

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: [How to filter WooCommerce products by custom attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15138113/1456376)

Comment: this is helpful, but... which files are?
Thanks for reply!

Comment: Also interesting: [WooCommerce Products Filter](http://www.woocommerce-filter.com)

Comment: In my case, i found the file, is : woocommerce.php in wp-content\themes\zerif-lite and now i can do this:
`code`
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['demo'])){
                                     //show products filtereds by attribute
    }
    else 
      woocommerce_content(); 
       ?>
`code`
But, how i can filter by attribute?
I created a function called woocommerce_content_demo and i put
`code`
  $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'tax_query' => array(
    array('attribute' => 'demo',),
   ),
  );
  
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
`code`
But i don't know get attribute param

Comment: my query should be like this 

SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE id IN (select post_id from wp_postmeta where meta_value like '%demo%')

and i think would work with something like this 

$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'tax_query' => array(
  'relation' => 'AND',
  array(
   'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
   'field'    => 'slug',
   'terms'    => array( 'action', 'comedy' ),
  ),
  array(
   'taxonomy' => 'actor',
   'field'    => 'term_id',
   'terms'    => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
   'operator' => 'NOT IN',
  ),
 ),
);

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got finally the result!

I have this:

```
$args = array ( 
     'post_type'  => 'product',
     'posts_per_page'  => 12,
     'meta_query' => array( 
         array( 
          'value' => 'demo', 
          'compare' => 'like'
         ), 
       ),
```

);

Thanks anyway for the help!