# Filter WooCommerce products by custom attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I import a huge amount of goods. Each already has custom attributes. How can I use them to filter products in a storefront? I cannot manually create such a huge number of attributes and assign them to each of the goods. Perhaps there is some kind of plugin?

P.S. I know that such a question [already exists here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138113/how-to-filter-woocommerce-products-by-custom-attribute), but it was asked back in 2013 and since then much has changed.

Waiting for help!
Thanks.

Comment: can you include what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Reigel, Hello, I have not tried anything yet, because I can’t find enough information.